# Finding various substrings in a provided string

Tags: java, python, algorithm

Got this for my interview question. Given an array of strings and a string (haystack), what is the fastest algorithm that takes that array of strings and finds out whether each string in the array is a substring of the haystack. I thought that the fastest algorithm was to find all substrings of haystack and store them in a set and then check each string in the array for membership in the set, but was informed this was not the fastest method.

Then, harder question: return the index of first occurrence of substring in the haystack. Since I didn't get the first part correct, I struggled with this one.

Comment: What answers did you give?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a job for the [Aho-Corasick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

[Suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree)? I believe you can both test for sub-strings and get their starting index.